# SQL correctly format integers as dates

Tags: c#, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am writing a program in C# and a part of it is to grab dates from a DB2 server. The dates are stored as length 4 integer values on the server. The date holds only month and day The problem I have is that they are stored with different accuracy. 
**EDIT:** The data type is numeric length 4 with no precision(So an integer length 4) but when the Select statement runs everything is returned as a string. Which is why I was using SubStr().

**Example**

One date is stored as **1003** representing the date **10/03**

Another date is stored as **805** representing **8/05**

The SQL code I use for pulling the dates

```
(SubStr(ML2DDM,0,3) ||'/'|| SubStr(ML2DDM,3,2))as Due__Date
```

The program returns the dates in the following format

10/03

80/5 <<<< Thats the problem

Is there a way to format the values correctly every time?

Comment: *'(SubStr(ML2DDM,0,3) ||'/'|| SubStr(ML2DDM,3,2))as Due__Date'*  
doesn't look like Sql      :)

Comment: @Dan Nor like c# :)

Comment: It's perfectly valid SQL, though using "0" as the starting position for SUBSTR() is unusual even if valid. And using SUBSTR() for an INTEGER column is also unwise, though perhaps meaningful in some cases when the value is auto-CAST to CHAR.

Comment: What does **('{'||ML2DDM||'}')** give for a result in your two example cases?

Comment: Please offer the DDL that is implied by *"stored as length 4 integer values"* to eliminate ambiguity. Best guess is 4-digit character strings, thus CHAR(4). But even if instead, the column is of the data type INTEGER [4-bytes], the results of the given expression are the same as CHAR(4) . Yet neither of those types would produce what was shown as the effect from the given SQL expression; instead, the results would be the following: `10 /05` and `80 /5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select left(right(repeat('0', 4) || trim(ML2DDM), 4), 2) || '/' ||  
 right(right(repeat('0', 4) || trim(ML2DDM), 4), 2)  as Due__Date
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are *integers*, it seems that doing string functions is a bad idea. I would just pull the integer back "as is", and deal with it in C#, then you have:

```
int month = val / 100;
int day = val % 100;
```

Which you can thendo *whatever you need to with*. I *expect* that your RDBMS *also* has integer division and modulo arithmetic built in, so you can probably do it at the server too. For example, in SQL Server (because I don't know DB2):

```
declare @v int = 805; -- obviously in real code this would be a column
select @v / 100 as [month], @v % 100 as [day]
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have integers stored as character.  As you wouldn't be able to use `SUBSTR()` on an integer column.

Couple of SQL solutions

Convert to zoned/packed decimal then used `DIGITS()` to convert back to character and include lead zeros

```
select 
  (SubStr(digits(dec(ML2DDM,4)),1,2) 
    ||'/'|| SubStr(digits(dec(ML2DDM,4)),3,2))as Due__Date
```

Add some lead zeros, then take the `RIGHT()` most characters...

```
select 
  (left(right(trim('0' || ML2DDM),4),2)
    ||'/'|| right(trim('0'|| ML2DDM),2) as Due__Date
```

The `TRIM()` is needed if the column is fixed length character instead of VARCHAR.

Comment: `SUBSTR()` on an INTEGER [or any numeric type] column is acceptable/supported because of the *implicit cast* feature between character and numeric. The likely problem of course, would be that the cast to character from numeric leaves the value left-justified; which, of course, would explain why the results from a number with fewer than four digits of significant precision could be problematic for finding any particular 10**N position when looking from left-to-right across the digits of a numeric of length N-1.

Answer (score 0):

In C# i'd do something like this:

```
var fullValue = ML2DDM;
var formattedDate = fullValue.Substring(0, fullValue.Length - 2) + "/" + fullValue.Substring(fullValue.Length - 2, 2);
```

I don't know any DB2, but perhaps the same approach works? Something like:

```
(SubStr(ML2DDM,0,length(ML2DDM)-2) ||'/'|| SubStr(ML2DDM,length(ML2DDM)-2,2))as Due__Date
```

Answer (score 0):

How to get bad data readable.  I use this technique mostly for making opening and closing tags or adding line feeds when outputing html, xml, plain text.  All there ways.

```
select 
case when length(trim(ml2ddm)) = 4 
then substring(ml2ddm,1,2) || '/' || substring(ml2ddm,3)
when substring(trim(ml2ddm,4,1) = ' ' 
then substring(ml2ddm,1,1) || '/' || substring(ml2ddm,2) 
else substring(ml2ddm,2,1) || '/' || substring(ml2ddm,3)  
end as somefunkydate
from somereallyfunkydata
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that, like so many posts, there is no DDL given, I can offer that:

Irrespective the DDL for ML2DDM being CHAR(4), VARCHAR(4), SMALLINT, DECIMAL, NUMERIC, BIGINT, or INTEGER [of the numeric types, then also ensured of no more than four digits of precision for any actual values, though the actual column precision is immaterial, but only if the column also is defined with zero-scale; which of course, is implied by the various INT types], the following expression should suffice to insert a `/` character between the MM and DD components of each **MMDD** datum that was stored with either a value of three digits ### or a value of four digits #### [where # represents any decimal digit zero through nine]; if the digits are stored as character strings, then they must be stored left-justified, and any non-digit data will be similarly edited, despite they are not valid representation of actual date-values, but neither would the edited result of the numeric values be ensured to be valid in that way:

```
   insert ( case length(rtrim(ML2DDM))  
             when 3 then '0' else '' end
            concat ML2DDM               
          , 3, 0, '/' ) as due__date_ins
```

Knowing the actual DDL could allow for a more succinct expression.

If an actual DATE data type result is desirable, an expression such as the one offered above could replace the `expr` in the following variation of a TIMESTAMP_FORMAT expression, to generate a TIMESTAMP with the current-year value `TO_DATE( expr, 'MMDD' )`, and that could be cast to DATE; e.g. `DATE( TO_DATE( expr, 'MMDD' ) )` Of course the results of this additional casting would **require** absolutely that the data values be stored as legitimate MMDD [or MDD] values.

**30-Sep-2016 Addendum**:
If the DDL for ML2DDM is numeric [non-float], then IIRC the implicit cast effect from numeric to character is casting to VARCHAR, so the following would be a quite simple expression to effect both MMDD to "MM/DD" and MDD to "MM/DD":

```
 insert ( LPAD( ML2DDM , 4, '0' ) , 3, 0, '/' ) as Due__Date
```